# How to remove all but first character before dot

Tags: string, bash

Suppose you have a string

```
anyString.ofSomeSort...
```

and you always need to trim it to

```
a.ofSomeSort...
```

so just keep the first character of the substring before the first dot.

Any ideas how a regex for this could look like?

Comment: [`(.{1})[^\.]*(\..*)` appears to work](http://regexr.com/4dfvp) - (group 1 contains first char, group 2 contains period + everything after)

Comment: The `{1}` isn't necessary; `.` by itself already matches exactly one character.

Comment: Is there a way for doing that in PowerShell? I tried $string.Split([Regex]::('s/(.)[^.]*/\1/')) but it just print the full string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)[^.]*/\1/' <<< 'anyString.ofSomeSort...'
a.ofSomeSort...
```

This captures the first character, then drops everything that's not a period after that first character.

Or with shell parameter expansion:

```
$ str='anyString.ofSomeSort...'
$ echo "${str:0:1}${str#${str%%.*}}"
a.ofSomeSort...
```

`${str:0:1}` is just the first character, and `${str#${str%%.*}}` retains everything from the first period on.

Comment: thanks! works :)

am I correct that if you remove an arrow sign < it will not print it to output but save it still?

Comment: @OlegBrendel No, `<<<` is a "here-string". To save the output to a variable, use `var=$(sed 's/\(.\)[^.]*/\1/' <<< 'anyString.ofSomeSort...')`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Is there a way for doing that in PowerShell?

I tried 

$string.Split([Regex]::('s/\(.\)[^.]*/\1/')) but it just print the full string

Comment: @OlegBrendel I don't know PowerShell at all.

Comment: It's fine I stopped using it and switched to Bash for this stuff
it works like Charms :)